# maven build doesnot consider new repository url

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

We had to change the repository location in the Pom.xml but when I run Maven(from within IntelliJ IDE) I notice in the logs that it still points to the old URL.
The maven repository in our organization has recently been moved to a new URL. The old URL is not valid anymore and hence I get connection timeout errors in the logs. I verified that all the instances of old URL has been updated in the POM.xmls.

Here is the excerpt of the logs. I do not find any references of the old URL anywhere on my machine.

```
[Proj Guard] Skipping disabled repository central
[Proj Guard] snapshot com.XYZ.Proj:Proj-libraries-conflict-guard:4.trunk-SNAPSHOT: checking for updates from mvnnexus
[Proj Guard] Checking for pre-existing User-Agent configuration.
[Proj Guard] Adding User-Agent configuration.
[Proj Guard] Connecting to repository: 'mvnnexus' with url: 'http://ABC.XYZ.corp:8081/nexus/content/groups/public'.
[Proj Guard] repository metadata for: 'snapshot com.XYZ.Proj:Proj-libraries-conflict-guard:4.trunk-SNAPSHOT' could not be retrieved from repository: mvnnexus due to an error: Error transferring file: Connection timed out: connect
org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Error transferring file: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.LightweightHttpWagon.fillInputData(LightweightHttpWagon.java:143)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.manager.DefaultWagonManager.getRemoteFile(DefaultWagonManager.java:546)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.manager.DefaultWagonManager.getArtifactMetadata(DefaultWagonManager.java:443)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.metadata.DefaultRepositoryMetadataManager.resolve(DefaultRepositoryMetadataManager.java:97)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.transform.AbstractVersionTransformation.resolveVersion(AbstractVersionTransformation.java:65)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.transform.SnapshotTransformation.transformForResolve(SnapshotTransformation.java:63)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.transform.DefaultArtifactTransformationManager.transformForResolve(DefaultArtifactTransformationManager.java:55)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:145)
```

The URL has been changed from(example) http:// ABC.XYZ.corp:8081/nexus/content/groups/public
to http:// nexus.Test.corp/nexus/content/groups/public but it does not seem to be picking.

Am I missing anything?
Please help me figure this out, let me know if you need any further info.

Comment: What happens if you run maven from command-line? does it still give the same error?

Comment: Are you fully sure the repository is not set in your settings.xml?

Comment: The same error when I ran from command-line too. The repository has been mentioned only in the pom.xml, i also verified in settings.xml it is not there.